# Trying to convert CSV file to JSON in nodejs gives syntax error while just requiring the csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, oracle-commerce-cloud

I have a dummy csv file uploaded in my nodejs application. All I want is to convert the CSV to JSON file.
But it gives syntax error while just requiring the csv file.

Below is the code in nodejs to parse file content

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const results = [];
let csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');
let fileInputName = require('./fileUpload/testingCSV.csv'); 
let fileOutputName = 'myproduct.json';
const fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream(fileInputName)
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
.on('end', () => {
 console.log(results);
});
csvToJson.generateJsonFileFromCsv(fileInputName,fileOutputName);
```

Below is the screenshot of console error

[image: Console error for invalid syntax]

Also, the actual csv file will contain a large number of data of products/accounts/userprofiles etc.
this is a dummy csv that I am trying to parse.

Please let me know what needs to be done .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your csv file is not correcly formated, what is the name of your nodejs file, and can you give us the error line 14 please ?

EDIT :

you are probably using an old version of Node.js. If this is the case, either `const csv = require('csv-parser');` to `const csv = require('csv-parser/lib/es5')`;`

Or

the csv file which is incorrect. Give the path directly on createreadstream

Comment: Error Line :14 is  "let fileInputName = require('./fileUpload/testingCSV.csv'); "

Comment: it didn't work. The problem is in the csv file it seems. Cant we use (',' , ':' , '.') in the headings of csv ?

Comment: If your file is a csv ";" separator, you cant use ";" instead of separator.

Check which separtor you use and correct it in you file

Comment: hey i was trying to require the csv file which is incorrect. hence the error.I gave the path directly on createreadstream and it worked. :)